# Why assigning nil to an optional variable is true in Swift?

Tags: swift, null, option-type

Why assigning nil to an optional variable is true in Swift?

```
if var y : String? = nil { // Why is this true?
    println("y is not nil")
}
```

But,

```
var z : String? = nil
if z { // But this is false?
    println("z is not nil")
}
```

Comment: even this behavior is as-designed, it is unexpected and need [a bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long story short: it was probably a bug with nil, and it is fixed in Beta 3. It is now false.

Nevertheless, you're probably doing something different than you wanted to. And there seems to be yet another bug.

Conditional assignments look like this:

```
if (var|let) x : T = y : T? {
    // this executes if y is not nil (T?.None), with x as its value
}
```

Notice that y is of type `T?` while x is of type `T`. And the check is for y being nil, not x...

So what you were trying to do (unless you actually wanted to use `String??`) was:

```
if var y : String = nil {
    // this is false
}
```

But your `nil` was treated as `String??` and not `String?` as you probably intended.
And it could be interpreted in two ways...

```
if let x: String? = String??.None {
    // this is false, happens in Beta 3
}

if let x: String? = String??.Some(String?.None) {
    // this is true, happens in Beta 2
}
```

You can check the value of `nil as String??` in a playground to confirm this.

What is actually ironic, is that your another example from the comments seems to be related to another bug, which is still present in Beta 3:

```
let NIL : String? = nil
NIL as String?? // this is String??.None
```

As much as `String??` seems useless and confusing, I would still expect it to be `.Some(.None)`.
I would say it is a bug.

Answer (score 3):

The way optional binding works is it checks whether the assignment was successful. In this case since you are able to assign nil to a String? it works.

In the second example you are passing just an optional instead of an assignment expression. In this case it checks to see if the optional contains a value, which it does not.

Comment: But it is still confusing that this will be false:
let NIL : String? = nil;
if let y : String? = NIL { /* But why this is false */
    println("y is not nil");
}

Comment: That does seem inconsistent. The main intent of optional binding in if statements is to conditionally turn an optional into an unwrapped, non-optional type. Assigning to *another* optional in the `if` statement (and not unwrapping it at all) seems to be a corner case that has not received careful consideration. Writing a bug report is probably a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand:

```
if var y : String? = nil { 
    println("y is not nil")
}
```

means:

if `y` **might** be `nil`, set `y` to be `nil` and print

2nd case:

```
var z : String? = nil
if z { // But this is false?
    println("z is not nil")
}
```

we know that `z` is `nil` => `if z` returns `false`

BTW, if you write in *not optional* way, you get `false`:

```
if var y : String = nil { //returns false
    println("y is not nil")
}
```

Comment: don't get you -- is this answer?